# Export Image with different bands and parameters in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I'm trying to export an image of a specific region that multiple times that has different parameters. I'm using Sentinel-2 imagery and would like to export true color, false color and SWIR imagery based off a single variable. The code I have looks like this:

```
//Set map centre
Map.setCenter(159.9737, -9.4336, 12.5)

var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[159.9024627043289, -9.391377171560114],
          [159.9024627043289, -9.482819760533483],
          [160.03773186936797, -9.482819760533483],
          [160.03773186936797, -9.391377171560114]]], null, false)

//Import Sentinel-2 Imagery
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2021-01-01')
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))

//clip to region of interest
var median = S2.median();
var clipped = median.clip(roi);

//add different visualisations to map
Map.addLayer(clipped, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 301.55555555555554, max: 2162}, 'True Colour')
Map.addLayer(clipped, {bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'], min: 215.9245283018868, max: 4181.5}, 'False Colour')
Map.addLayer(clipped, {bands: ['B12', 'B8', 'B4'], min: 68.14285714285714, max: 3633}, 'SWIR')
```

Any suggestions on how I can export the three different types of visualisation?

Comment: `Map.addLayer` with parameters is a simple representation, is a digital image instead of a raster image. Are you trying to export the map or the source image?

Comment: I'm trying to export the representation within the selected region rather than the whole map.